# Remove a string when a condition is met

Tags: bash, awk, sed, gawk

I have a tab-separated text, within the text is a string that appears on several occasions and I need to remove it when accompanied by other strings.

```
A       B      C        D   E   F   G   H   I   J
string  string string   car29   ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  string # We don't do anything
string  string string   pool    car29   ""  ""  ""  ""  string # Remove car29
string  string string   fifo    pool    car29   ""  ""  ""  string # Remove car29
string  string string   car29   ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  string # We don't do anything
```

The key word is car29 and we just act on rows where this word appears

Expected Output

```
A       B      C        D   E   F   G   H   I   J
string  string string   car29   ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  string 
string  string string   pool    ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  string 
string  string string   fifo    pool    ""  ""  ""  ""  string 
string  string string   car29   ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  string
```

Comment: Edit the question to show what output you want and why.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/242504/13792

Comment: Unclear when to remove it. Please add some more logic to the question.

Comment: So do you want to remove rows that have car29 anywhere? The question says "when accompanied by other strings", what are the other strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `sed`

```
sed '/\(.*"".*\)\{5\}/! s/car29/""/' <<\eof
A       B      C        D   E   F   G   H   I   J
string  string string   car29   ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  string # We don't do anything
string  string string   pool    car29   ""  ""  ""  ""  string # Remove car29
string  string string   fifo    pool    car29   ""  ""  ""  string # Remove car29
string  string string   car29   ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  string # We don't do anything
eof

A       B      C        D   E   F   G   H   I   J
string  string string   car29   ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  string # We don't do anything
string  string string   pool    ""   ""  ""  ""  ""  string # Remove car29
string  string string   fifo    pool    ""   ""  ""  ""  string # Remove car29
string  string string   car29   ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  string # We don't do anything
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -F'/\t/' -ape 's/(^|(?<=\t))car29($|(?=\t))/""/g if grep $_ ne "car29" && $_ ne q(""), @F[3..8]'
```

- `-F` sets the column separator
- `-a` splits to colunns (into the `@F` array)
- `-p` processes input line by line, printing the results
- the substitution happens only if the column 3 .. 8 (just guessing, your specification is vague) isn't empty and is different to `car29`
- the substitution replaces `car29` by `""` when it's preceded by the beginning of line or a tab, and followed by the end of line or a tab. Look around assertions are used for cases where there are several `car29`s neighbouring. The `^` and `$` are probably not needed, as the first three columns and the last one in your examples never contain `car29` (incomplete spec again).